# Jquery Filer Plugin - Adding whitelist extensions

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-filer

I am using the [Jquery Filer](http://filer.grandesign.md/) plugin for uploading images. Now I want to use a whitelist of only jpg/jpeg images. For using such whitelist there is an option called "extensions", which can hold a `{null, Array}` as the documentation says.

However, I was not able to get it working. I tried this:

```
extensions: {
    jpeg: "jpeg",
    jpg: "jpg"
},
```

and I tried this

```
extensions: {
    jpeg: "image/jpeg",
    jpg: "image/jpg"
},
```

But both methods doesn't work because it says `Invalid format` when trying to upload a `.jpg` image.

Anyone who can help me to create a whitelist of image-type using the jQuery.Filer plugin?

Repo + documentation
https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer

Comment: If you don't specify an `extensions:` object at all, do you still get the `invalid format` error?

Comment: When I don't specify the extension it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/CreativeDream/jquery.filer):

> extensions: Whitelist for file extension. {null, Array}

the `extensions` option is expecting an array.  Try this:

```
extensions: [
    'jpg',
    'jpeg'
]
```

but remember this is only filtering by extension - nothing preventing me from sending you `myHorribleVirus.exe.jpg` ;-)

Comment: That did the job, thanks! And yes, I will implement some server-side checks too, thanks again!